# Number of balls of the same color remaining in an urn.

Tags: probability

An urn contains two types of balls, black and white. Initially it has $n$ black balls and $n$ white balls. Balls are picked uniformly at random up one by one to the time there remains only balls with the same color in the urn.

What is the distribution of the number of balls remaining in the urn once only balls of the same color are left ? What is the limit of that distribution as n gets large ?

(Beware this turns out to be very distinct from the Banach matchbox problem, since the picking system is very different)

Comment: What is "*Law number*"?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Banach is equally likely to take its match from either pocket. Banach does not do that here.

Comment: The previous comment was to expand an a (deleted) comment asking what is the difference with Banach matchbox problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the limiting random variable is nothing but the Geom(1/2) on $\mathbb N =\{1,2,3, \ldots \}$ distribution, with expectation 2, by time reversal...

For a fixed integer $n$, and $1 \le k \le n$, one indeed has:

$$P(X=k)= 2 * \frac{{2n-k-1 \choose n-k}}{{2n \choose n}} $$

EDIT, to answer a comment : The numerator is the number of configurations where the last $k$ balls all have the same color (either black or white, hence the factor 2), but not the $k+1$ last : this equivalently means the $n-k$ other balls (of that same color) have to be distributed within the $2n-k-1$ first spots. The denominator is for the total number of configurations.

Comment: I upvoted this before you added the fixed formula and now I want to upvote it some more and I cannot and this makes me sad.

Comment: Nice, and the acceptance makes clear that it is understood by the OP. You could make it more accessible for others though by adding some explanation.